# Need help with manipulating some string

Tags: c#, asp.net

ok so I have a string, let's say..

```
string s="My Page";
```

Now I want to manipulate this string s and make it "mypage" i.e. all small letters and no spaces in between and then store this value in another string. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
s = s.ToLower().Replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: to put it in a new string:  string newS = s.ToLower().Replace(" ", "");

Comment: @Russ C: Yeah, I realized that after I typed it. I was really just trying to point out that you would have to reassign the variable (s) since strings are immutable in C#.

Answer (score 4):

```
s = s.ToLower().Replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: @jlafay: I was 22 seconds faster :P

Comment: @jlafay, I was just messing around, you didnt have to do that.

Comment: Yep, Jason beat me to it. Really good answer though, wouldn't you say Jason? ;)